# how to match up setting in security/limits.conf with nginx.conf for at least 5k users per minute?

Tags: linux, nginx

I know by reading similar posts that

worker_connections * worker_processes = user connections per second

so I would need to set soft nofile to same as above result?

Also, how do I count max capacity of max nofile in limits.conf?
Is it "sysctl fs.max-file"?

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. `worker_connections * worker_processes` gives you the maximum amount of connections that nginx will accept at a given time, not the amount of connection per a period of time. The number of connection per second depends on user count, session duration, keepalive timeout and the amount of ressource users are asking for.

Comment: user counts means if I set on tsung a session with 10 request, each request represents a user?